# Handling blank option value with AJAX requests

Tags: php, ajax

I have noticed when looking at the DOM tree for my code that `<option value="">` is changed to `<option value>` and this is causing problems when I try to check via AJAX if the user has selected the blank option in the drop down menu.

I pass the value selected in the drop down to the PHP code below using AJAX, but if the option was blank I get erros. Here's what I've tried:

FORM:

```
<label for="district" class="general medium">District</label>
<select id="district" name="district" class="textbox short_field" onchange="show_locations(this.value);">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
```

AJAX SCRIPT:

```
<script>
function show_locations(str) {

if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("locations_dropdown").innerHTML="";
    return;
    }

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        var a = xmlhttp.responseText;
            a = JSON.parse(a);
            document.getElementById("locations_dropdown").innerHTML=a.location;
            document.getElementById("dm").innerHTML=a.dm;
            document.getElementById("dm_email").innerHTML=a.dm_email;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","includes/get_locations.php?d="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
```

Then, my PHP file get_locations.php retrieves the value of d like so:

```
<?php
$district_id = $_REQUEST['d'];

if($district_id == NULL){
    $location_box = '<select id="location_id" name="location_id" class="textbox short_field required" onchange="show_sm(this.value);">
    <option value=""></option>
    </select>';

    $dm_box = '<input type="text" id="district_manager" name="district_manager" class="textbox short_field" value="">';

    $dm_email = '<input type="email" id="send_to_dm" name="send_to_dm" class="textbox long_field" value="">';

    } else {
        $location_box = '<select id="location_id" name="location_id" class="textbox short_field required" onchange="show_sm(this.value);">
        <option value="#"></option>';

        $query = 'SELECT l.id, l.banner_id, l.location, b.code
                  FROM locations l
                  INNER JOIN banners b ON (l.banner_id = b.id)
                  WHERE district_id =' . $district_id;

        $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        if (!result) {
            die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
        }

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          $location_box .= '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '"';
          if($row['id'] == $location) { $location_box .= ' selected';} ;
          $location_box .= '>' . $row['code'] . ' ' . $row['location'] . '</option>';
        }

        $location_box .= '</select>';
//Get DM Info ...

        $query = "SELECT id FROM locations WHERE district_id = '{$district_id}' AND number = 0";

        $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            if (!result) {
                die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
            }

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $dm_location = $row['id'];
            }

        $query = "SELECT first_name, last_name, email FROM users WHERE location_id = " . $dm_location . " AND position_id = 2";

        $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            if (!result) {
                die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
            }

            if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
                    $dm_box = '<input type="text" id="district_manager" name="district_manager" class="textbox short_field" value="Not found. Enter manually.">';
                    $dm_email = '<input type="email" id="send_to_dm" name="send_to_dm" class="textbox long_field" value="Not found. Enter manually.">';
            }

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $dm = $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'];
            $email = $row['email'];

            $dm_box = '<input type="text" id="district_manager" name="district_manager" class="textbox short_field" value="' . $dm . '">';

            $dm_email = '<input type="email" id="send_to_dm" name="send_to_dm" class="textbox long_field" value="' . $email . '">';
            }

}



echo json_encode(array('location'=>$location_box,'dm'=>$dm_box,'dm_email'=>$dm_email));
?>
```

But this doesn't recognize that the value selected had `value=""` so I guess $_REQUEST['d'] is not NULL?

I also tried `if(!isset($_REQUEST['d']));` which didn't work either.

The code just gives me errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where and how do you set the `str` variable ?

Comment: I edited my post to show more detail.

Comment: I also tried changing value="" to value="#" and that seemed to do it, but that solution caused other problems elsewhere with my validation script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this on js side;

```
function show_locations() {

    var e = document.getElementById("district");
    var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    if (str.length < 1) {
        document.getElementById("locations_dropdown").innerHTML="";
        return;
        }

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            var a = xmlhttp.responseText;
                a = JSON.parse(a);
                document.getElementById("locations_dropdown").innerHTML=a.location;
                document.getElementById("dm").innerHTML=a.dm;
                document.getElementById("dm_email").innerHTML=a.dm_email;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","includes/get_locations.php?d="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

And in selectbox;

```
<select id="district" name="district" class="textbox short_field" onchange="show_locations();">
```

And in php side, check;

```
if(empty($district_id)) {...
```

You can see working demo here: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fks6t/1/)**

Comment: That didn't work. If I select `option value="1"` the get_locations.php file does what's expected, but when I then reselect `option value=""` it malfunctions. I guess `if($district_id == NULL)` still doesn't recognize value="" as null.

Comment: I see what you did and I just tried it, but still the option `if(district_id == NULL){ do this } doesn't trigger.

Comment: let me post the full get_locations.php code in my original post so you can see better what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Okay. As you can see, I want the get_locations.php file to replace the select box with different options if $district_id == NULL or if it is not NULL. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way. Thanks for you time!

Comment: Make your check like `if(empty($district_id)) {.` not `if($district_id == NULL) {.`

Comment: Just tried that, but it still won't work. The select box just disappears.

Comment: What is the response come from php file? I need to check format

Comment: I think I just solved it by taking out the `if (str =="")` or `if (str.length < 1)` part completely. I think that part was replacing my select box with a blank. Do you foresee any issues if I leave that part out of the AJAX completely?

Comment: yes yo need to remove it, you are checking it at backend already

Comment: I don't think there was a response because AJAX was saying to make innerHTML="" if the string was blank or less than 1. So, I don't think the variable was being sent to the PHP file at all in that case.

Comment: Thank you so much! You helped me think my way through it.